# How to solve battery charge issue on Galaxy A04

Tags: samsung, charging

I don't know if it's the recommended 6 hour charge policy that I didn't follow when I bought this phone but it's behaving weirdly when the battery charge reaches zero percent. It goes off and then when I plug it into the AC charger it shows the lightning sign without showing the number which in this case is 0 going upwards. This goes on for hours until I long press the power button and volume down button(several times) to completely drain the battery. This behavior persists on every battery drain and I would like to get rid of it permanently, Thanks.

Comment: What is the "6 hour charge policy"? Note that letting the battery reach 0% and the phone shuts down is the best way to degrade the battery and additionally there is a small chance to destroy the file-system and loose all your data. LiO batteries should best be kept between 20 and 80% to prolong their life.

Comment: The six hoirs charge is usually recommended for new phones where you are needed to charge the battery for at least six hours. To prolong the lives of batteries, Samsung gave us an option to limit maximum battery charge to 85 percent.

Comment: Based on your description, your phone is not brand new. The 85% limit is nice, but the opposite direction (deep discharge) can cause even more damage to the battery.

Comment: @Robert, had another android phone whuch was samsung brand and didn't refuse to update the charge percentage when plugged in. This one gets stuck at the lightning logo forever without accepting charge. Is it a must to keep phone charge between 5 and 85 percent?

Comment: @Robert, another user posted a similar issue to Samsung forums and Samsung recommended the deep drain. How is it bad?